# How to uppercase the command line argument?

Tags: bash, string, case-sensitivity

I searched SO and found that to uppercase a string following would work

```
str="Some string"
echo ${str^^}
```

But I tried to do a similar thing on a command-line argument, which gave me the following error

#### Tried

```
#!/bin/bash
             ## Output
echo ${1^^}  ## line 3: ${1^^}: bad substitution
echo {$1^^}  ## No error, but output was still smaller case i.e. no effect
```

How could we do this?

Comment: It [works for me](http://pastebin.com/zZHvnvtp) just fine. Post your entire script, the error is probably elsewhere. Is your shebang pointing to `bash`?

Comment: possible same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/converting-string-to-lower-case-in-bash-shell-scripting

Answer (score 202, accepted):

The syntax `str^^` which you are trying is available from Bash 4.0 and above. Perhaps yours is an older version (or you ran the script with `sh` explicitly):

Try this:

```
str="Some string"
printf '%s\n' "$str" | awk '{ print toupper($0) }'
```

Comment: From mtk's words I understood that case modification actually works for him with variables.

Comment: @manatwork That is not clearly stated in the initial question. The bad substitution error message is the same as you would get with older bash versions.

Comment: You are correct. I checked the version, its 3.2.25. Your solution works and also I tried `tr '[a-z]' [[A-Z]'`.

Comment: @mtk That should be `tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`.

Comment: I'm running `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0)`, and I get the same error as OP, so I don't think this is available on any `bash` 4.0 and above as you say.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `printf` instead of `echo`?

Comment: @ZoeyHewll – `printf` doesn't accept options, so it's much more reliable and predictable given something like `str="-n"` (try `echo "-n"` or `echo -- "-n"` vs `printf "%s\n" "-n"`).

Answer (score 164):

```
echo "lowercase" | tr a-z A-Z
```

Output:

```
LOWERCASE
```

Comment: I think POSIX does not require the `/` as in `tr /a-z/ /A-Z/` before my edit: this just works because it replaces `/` by `/` but is useless: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html There also exists the more obscure and less useful `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`.

Comment: Correct.  tr is very different, but it works.

Comment: umlauts are not working with this.

Comment: As @CiroSantilli冠状病毒审查六四事件法轮功 mentioned, you can use `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' to handle non-a-z characters. (Indeed, the "less useful" comment seems to be the opposite. using lower/upper covers a wider range of characters.)

Answer (score 35):

Be careful with `tr` unless `A-Z` is all you use. For other locales even `'[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` fails, only `awk`'s `toupper` and bash (v4+) works:

```bash
$ str="abcåäö"

$ echo "$str" | tr '/a-z/' '/A-Z/'
ABCåäö

$ echo "$str" | LC_ALL=sv_SE tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
ABCåäö

$ echo "$str" | awk '{print toupper($0)}'
ABCÅÄÖ

$ echo ${str^^} # Bash 4.0 and later
ABCÅÄÖ

$ STR="ABCÅÄÖ"
$ echo ${STR,,}
abcåäö
```

Comment: FWIW, `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` is working now for your example on OS X at least (also with `LC_ALL=sv_SE`)

Comment: That's a limitation (and non-compliance) of GNU `tr` and a few others. `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'` is *meant* to work on any letter that have an uppercase variant in the locale, not just `A-Z` (whatever `A-Z` means, does it include `É`, `Æ`?). You have the same problem with some implementations of `awk` with `toupper()`, such as `mawk`, the default `awk` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, you could switch to ksh or zsh which have had case conversion support for decades (long before `bash`'s `${var^^}` added in 4.0), though with a different syntax:

```
#! /bin/ksh -
typeset -u upper="$1"
printf '%s\n' "$upper"
```

(also works with `zsh`; note that in pdksh/mksh, that only works for ASCII letters).

With `zsh`, you can also use the `U` parameter expansion flag or the csh style¹ `u` modifier:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
printf '%s\n' "${(U)1}" "$1:u"
```

POSIXLY, you can use:

```
awk -- 'BEGIN{print toupper(ARGV[1])}' "$1"
```

There's also:

```
printf '%s\n' "$1" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

But in a few implementations, including GNU `tr`, that only works for single-byte characters (so in UTF-8 locales, only on ASCII letters, not accented letters of the Latin alphabet, not ligatures, not letters from other alphabets that also have a concept of *case* such as the  Greek or Cyrillic alphabets).

In practice, none of those work for characters that don't have a single-character uppercase version such as `ﬃ` whose uppercase is `FFI` or the German `ß`. `perl`'s `uc` (`u`pper `c`ase) would work for those:

```
$ perl -CSA -le 'print uc for @ARGV' -- groß suﬃx
GROSS
SUFFIX
```

Here with `-CLSA` to specify that the `S`tdio streams and `A`rguments are meant to be encoded in UTF-8 as long as UTF-8 is the charmap used in the `L`ocale.

---

<sup>¹ though that modifier specifically is originally from zsh, already there in 1.0 from 1990, copied by tcsh later in 1992 for 6.01.03.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the string:

```shell
echo "${str^^}"
```

Answer (score -1):

If someone is still getting error trying `${str^^}`, you can try `python -c` or `perl` It is likely because bash version is lower than 4.

But, so far bash 4 or over is working swiftly with the existing solution.

```
L2U="I will be upper"
```

**Using `python -c` in bash**

```
python -c "print('$L2U'.upper())"
I WILL BE UPPER
```

Similarly it also can be used to **capitalise** with:

```
service="bootup.sh on home"
python -c "print('$service'.capitalize())"
Bootup.sh on home
```

**Using `perl`**

```
echo $L2U | perl -ne 'print "\U$_"'
I WILL BE UPPER
```

Comment: While using `python` or `perl` here is a good idea, the fact that you embed the expansion of the shell variable in the code passed to those interpreters (in the python ones) make it a code injection vulnerability and is very bad practice. It may explain the downvotes you got. You also forgot the quotes around `$L2U` in the last one, and remember `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data.