# Replace awk and tr with just awk for converting to lowercase

Tags: awk

Not a duplicate question, as I am asking for awk specifically.

I have the following command to convert everything to lowercase, and then reprint out substrings in a certain order.

```
cat words |tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |awk '{ print substr($1,1,1)$2."texttoappend"}'
```

It works perfectly, but I can't help but think it would be cleaner if I could do it all within awk. Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021899/can-i-use-awk-to-convert-all-the-lower-case-letters-into-upper-case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash - how to uppercase the command line argument?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51983/bash-how-to-uppercase-the-command-line-argument)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. I'm not asking to use bash or any solution, I'm asking specifically to use awk. @muru when I try to use tolower on a substr I get an error, can they be used together?

Comment: `echo FOO bar | awk '{print tolower(substr($1,1,1)$2)}'` works fine for me.

Comment: Which version of awk?

Comment: @muru erm...nevermind, working for me now also.

Comment: @muru, I found the problem I think, when attempting to append text I get an error about a runaway string constant. I'm trying { print tolower(substr($1,1,1) $2)."texttoappend"}' -- I'm finding it hard to get the version of awk, but it is whatever shipped with ubuntu recently.

Answer (score 2):

If you want everything to be in lower text, this should work

```
echo FIELD1 FIELD2 | awk '{print tolower(substr($1,1,1)$2".""TextToAppend")}'
```

**output is ffield2.texttoappend**

If you want texttoappend as it is, this should work

```
echo FIELD1 FIELD2 | awk '{print tolower(substr($1,1,1)$2)".""TextToAppend"}'
```

**output is ffield2.TextToAppend**