# Convert arg to uppercase to pass as variable

Tags: bash, shell, csh

Is there a way to convert the command line argument to uppercase and pass it as a variable within the script being invoked?

```
Eg. ./deploy_app.csh 1.2.3.4 middleware
```

should convert middleware to MIDDLEWARE and pass it as a variable inside the script where ever it requires a variable substitution.

I know that I can use echo and awk to get this output but trying to check if there is a way without using that combination

Comment: is that a CSH script? You've tagged the "bash" shell in the Q.

Comment: The script being run is a `csh` script, but it's possible the shell being used is `bash`.

Comment: I assume you're right, Tim, but in theory a "foo.csh" script *could* have some other shell in the she-bang line. Hopefully the OP will clarify.

Comment: Yes the script being run is a csh but the shell being used for this conversion and variable substitution is bash

Comment: Relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51983/bash-how-to-uppercase-the-command-line-argument.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using bash (4.0+), inside the script:

```
newvarname=${3^^}
```

Using tcsh:

```
set newvarname = $3:u:q
```

Using zsh:

```
# tcsh-like syntax:
newvarname=${3:u} # or just $3:u
# native syntax:
newvarname=${(U)3}
```

Using `tr` instead of shell features (though limited to single-byte letters only in some `tr` implementations like GNU's):

```
newvarname=$(printf "%s" "$3" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
```

This page summarizes a lot of features of different UNIX shells, including text manipulation: http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells.

Answer (score 8):

In Bash you can declare a variable as uppercase with `-u`, and it then converts automatically.

```
$ declare -u a
$ b=abcd
$ a=$b
$ echo $a
ABCD
```

Comment: Note that it comes from `ksh` (where you'd use `typeset` instead of `declare`). Also note that it also has the side effect of limiting the scope of the variable to the current function (and the previous value of the variable be restored upon exit of the function).